# Spring-MVC/AngularJs problems with dateField during the http put request

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm starting a new spring mvc project.
in my project, i have to manage some enties date as simple date, and others as DateTime

I configured the dateFormatter in my spring-mvc xml dispatcher as followed (here is my xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<!-- Login Interceptor -->
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/protected/**" />
        <bean class="softbank.ui.interceptor.LoginInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <!-- workaround to fix IE8 problem -->
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- i18n -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/i18n" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<!-- View Handler -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="xml" value="text/xml" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="less" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="objectMapper"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
    p:indentOutput="true" p:simpleDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss">
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
    p:targetObject-ref="objectMapper" p:targetMethod="registerModule">
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper" />
        </bean>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

On my UI i have a form with a Date Field.
I'm using AngularJs to send my data to the server.
during the http post request, there is no problemnt. but during the http PUT request, i'm still getting a 400 error(Bad Request).

Now, when i change in my sprig-mvc xml file, the formatting date as followed "yyyy-MM-dd" without "HH:mm:ss"; the PUT request succeed.

But, in my application, i have to manage some date fields as Date and some others as DateTime.

Here is in my angular Controller how i send my http PUT request:

```
$scope.updateClient = function(clientForm) {
    var url = $scope.url + $scope.client.id;                    
    var config = {};
        $http.put(url, $scope.client, config).success(
            function(data) {
                $state.go("clientDetails", {clientId:data.id});
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Error"+status);
        });

  };
```

And in my Spring-Mvc ClientController, here is how i handle my PUT request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable("id") Long clientId, @RequestBody Client client) {
    clientService.save(client);
    client = clientService.findById(clientId);
    return new ResponseEntity<Client>(client, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It seems like, due to the date formatting configured in the spring dispatcher xml file, my object (containing a date field) does not arrive on the server during the http PUT request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .. please provide only minimal required information

Comment: "What is wrong with my update process?" Who knows ... you say you're using JPA but present absolutely no JPA update code. Why not actually DEBUG it ... by looking at the JPA providers LOG?

Comment: in fact, the problem occur during the transition of data from client side to server side. and it only occur with the http put request. i'm getting a 400 (Bad Request) code error when i try to send a Client object with http put request. 

when i change the configuration of dateFormatter in my spring-mvc xml file as "yyyy-MM-dd", without hours, the problem disappear. but i do not want to use this format in my project (the object i'm sending contents a Date field)

Comment: ok sidgate, i modified my post mentioning only the essential